Bugs and Errors on publishing power app on sharepoint
The version on Preview mode of Power app is different from what I have seen on the Sharepoint site, given that I have already saved and published the power app to Sharepoint
I tried to code the Power app form on one of the Sharepoint site list, so basically I implement the code on Power app by pressing 'customize with power app' button on the sharepoint list. However when I make changes on power app, saved and published it, the form on Sharepoint doesn't seems like it has changed, May I ask how to solve it?
Also, when I patch items into the Sharepoint using preview mode in power app, it works well (I even tested it with LookUp('Form', ID=SharePointForm1.LastSubmit.ID,'item') and the content is being updated.
However when i test it in the sharepoint list, it doesn't work at all, and the  LookUp('Form', ID=SharePointForm1.LastSubmit.ID,'item') shows nothing, may I ask how to fix this issure,
Many thanks
